# upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream in Moodle with Nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx, redhat, moodle

I have a problem when I migrated a moodle from Windows Server (IIS) to Linux (Nginx).

I get the following in the Nginx error.log:

```
2023/06/05 11:39:24 [error] 364769#364769: *4 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.198.221, server: _, request: "GET /pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_fordson%2Fslide1image%2F1685976991%2Funnamed%20%285%29.jpg HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/theme/styles.php?theme=fordson&rev=1685976991_1&type=all"
2023/06/05 11:39:24 [error] 364769#364769: *4 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.198.221, server: _, request: "GET /pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_fordson%2Ffavicon%2F1685976991%2FUM-02.png HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/my/"
2023/06/05 11:41:53 [error] 364833#364833: *6 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.198.221, server: _, request: "GET /pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_fordson%2Fslide1image%2F1685976991%2Funnamed%20%285%29.jpg HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/theme/styles.php?theme=fordson&rev=1685976991_1&type=all"
2023/06/05 11:41:54 [error] 364833#364833: *6 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.198.221, server: _, request: "GET /pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_fordson%2Ffavicon%2F1685976991%2FUM-02.png HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/my/"
2023/06/05 11:41:58 [error] 364833#364833: *6 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.198.221, server: _, request: "GET /pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_fordson%2Fslide1image%2F1685976991%2Funnamed%20%285%29.jpg HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/theme/styles.php?theme=fordson&rev=1685976991_1&type=all"
2023/06/05 11:41:58 [error] 364833#364833: *6 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.198.221, server: _, request: "GET /pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_fordson%2Ffavicon%2F1685976991%2FUM-02.png HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/my/"
2023/06/05 11:42:12 [error] 364860#364860: *4 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.198.221, server: _, request: "GET /pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_fordson%2Fslide1image%2F1685976991%2Funnamed%20%285%29.jpg HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/theme/styles.php?theme=fordson&rev=1685976991_1&type=all"
2023/06/05 11:42:12 [error] 364860#364860: *4 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.198.221, server: _, request: "GET /pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_fordson%2Ffavicon%2F1685976991%2FUM-02.png HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/my/"
```

The configuration files are the following:
nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        rewrite ^/(.*\.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;

        location /dataroot/ {
                internal;
                alias /moodle/data/moodledata/; # ensure the path ends with /
        }

    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/wildcard.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/wildcard.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        rewrite ^/(.*\.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;

        location /dataroot/ {
                internal;
                alias /moodle/data/moodledata/; # ensure the path ends with /
        }
    }

}
```

php.conf

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
}
```

config.php (moodle)

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'sqlsrv';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = '{HOST}';
$CFG->dbname    = '{DBNAME}';
$CFG->dbuser    = '{DBUSER}';
$CFG->dbpass    = '{DBPASS}';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://example.com';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/moodle/data/moodledata/';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->disableupdatenotifications = true;

$CFG->xsendfile = 'X-Accel-Redirect';
$CFG->xsendfilealiases = array(
        '/dataroot/' => $CFG->dataroot
);


$CFG->slasharguments = false;

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(_DIR_ . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

I already checked all the configuration, both moodle, Nginx, PHP (php-fpm) and that error has not been solved.

The error is that there are files, mostly images (png, jpg, etc) that are not displayed and generates a 404 error.

I'm using:
PHP 7.4.33
Nginx 1.20.1

Thanks for your support

Comment: Check wherever PHP is logging its errors for more information.

Comment: @Sammitch It seems that the problem is being caused by the copy of the moodledata from a Windows NAS to Linux, I will continue investigating